# Page formatting on different monitors

Tags: html, css

I have recently began to make a webpage and have run into a problem.  The format looks strange on some monitors.  I have to change this div for it to work on any other computer monitor different from mine.

```
<DIV STYLE="position:absolute; top:100px; left: 15%; width:950px; height:1150px">
```

I was wondering if there is a way I could fix this.  I do have a background image and on different monitors the text can be shifted all the way to the left.  Is there any way I could fix this?

P.S. I thought of adding a text box that you could put a percent into and have that be the position to the left in the div.

Comment: Improvise your question. "format looks strange" is not providing info.. you could share screen snap to illustrate. Need more clarity on your question.

Answer (score 0):

Minimal use of property,

```
Position:absolute
```

is always a good way to code.
Use this only when there are no other options.  If you can do the same task using relative or static, prefer those first.